# Conteúdo fora de while php

Tags: php, mysql

Bem eu tenho um `loop while` que mostra todos os meus posts na página e para cada post eu tenho um `input box` para comentar o post. Eu preciso de uma forma colocar ele (input) fora do while mas que fique em todos os posts. Como posso fazer isso?

**Código**

```
$result_post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE estabelecimento_id = $id_estabelecimento ORDER BY data DESC");
while ($row_posts = mysql_fetch_object($result_post)) {
    $result_user_anex = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_social WHERE id = $row_posts->user_id");
    $row_user_anex = mysql_fetch_object($result_user_anex);
?>

<section class="container" style="margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; border-top-left-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div style="float:left; margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">
                    <img width="50" height="50" src="<?= $row_user_anex->user_foto ?>"/>
                </div>
                <h3 style="float:left; margin:15px 0px 0px 10px;"><?= utf8_encode($row_user_anex->fb_nome); ?></h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>      
    <p><?= utf8_encode($row_posts->opiniao); ?></p>
    <script>
        FB.init({ appId: '1404139796547995', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
        function post_fb<?= $row_posts->id_post; ?>() {  
            FB.login(function(response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed', 
                    message     : "Vê este comentário sobre <?= $row_cat->titulo; ?> no @SabeOnde",
                    link        : '<?= $row->link_site; ?>',
                    picture     : 'http://sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/capa/<?= $row_capa->id_anexo; ?>.<?= $row_capa->tipo ?>',
                    name        : '<?= $row_cat->titulo; ?> | SabeOnde',
                    from        : '<?= $_SESSION['FBID'] ?>',
                    description : '<?= $row_posts->opiniao; ?>'                      
                },
                function(response) {
                    if (response && response.post_id) {
                        alert('Comentário Partilhado com sucesso!');
                    } else {
                        alert('Falha ao partilhar o comentário');
                    }
                });
                } else {
                    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
            }, {scope: 'publish_actions, publish_stream'});
        return false;
    }
    </script>  
    <div style="float:left; margin:0px 5px 10px 0px;"><a href="#">Gosto</a></div>
    <div style="float:left; margin:0px 5px 10px 0px;"><a href="#" >Comentar</a></div>
    <div style="float:left; margin:0px 5px 10px 0px;"><a href="#" onClick="post_fb<?= $row_posts->id_post; ?>()">Partilhar</a></div>
</section>
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?= $row_posts->id_post;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?= $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>"/>
<table border="0" bgcolor="#E9EAED" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="10%">
            <div style="padding:15px 5px 5px 20px;"><img width="33" height="33" src="<?= $_SESSION['user_foto'] ?>"/></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" width="90%">
            <div style="padding:15px 20px 15px 5px;"><input type="text" style="width:100%; height:33px;" placeholder="Escreve um comentário..." id="comentario" name="comentario" value=""></div>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" style="display:none;" value=" Submit Comment " />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código que você tem até agora?

Comment: Já esta colocado

Comment: Arrumei um pouco seu código fonte, tentei melhorá-lo mas o que você solicitou ainda não foi implementado.

Comment: foi esta em baixo a tabela que tem a input box dos comentarios

Comment: eu só quero achar uma maneira de tirar essa tabela de fora do while mas que repita em todos os posts percebeu ?

Comment: Sim, mas seu código estava mal formatado, da forma que está agora é mais legível; Única maneira que pensei até o momento é você fazer uma função separada e só passar os parâmetros para ela; Uma classe por exemplo...

Comment: claro que sim obrigado mas sabe como poderei fazer isso ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21313/discussion-between-rafael-withoeft-and-cesar-sousa).